# laravel 5.2 blade template failing to parse

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an issue with a laravel 5.2 site I'm working on. I have a master (`main`) layout that I'm using to set the main elements of the page up, and it's being used in the welcome page (that extends it) with no problem.

However, in some of the subpages I keep getting an error from the compiled view:

`<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.main, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>`

The error is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '__data' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'`

There's literally nothing in my view except the title and the main content element, where I'm trying to dump a variable. The error is coming from Laravel, not my code (as far as I can tell).

This is the whole view:

```
@extends('layouts.main)

@section('title', 'another page!')

@section('content')
{{dd($myvar)}}
@endsection
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Please check the first line:

```
@extends('layouts.main)
```

The closing single quote (`'`) is missing. It should be:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for that. I have been looking at a screen too long today!

Comment: welp, that's an embarrassing solution. PHPstorm doesn't auto add the second `'` like they do everywhere else with empty strings, hence the upvotes

Comment: I still don't know why I made this stupid mistake :(

Comment: How did you know? ;P

Comment: I can't believe that was my error. Laughing at myself right now

Answer (score 3):

Use this as your first line:

```php
@extends('layouts.main')
```

We often forget to put `'` on last word. Happens!